# How can I create an rss file in node.js?

Tags: xml, node.js, rss

How would I go about generating or updating an rss file in node.js?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

https://github.com/dylang/node-rss - RSS feed generator for Node

Fast and simple Javascript-based RSS generator/builder for Node projects.

The next time you need a node.js module, look here: http://search.npmjs.org/